# How do I find the control to test against with CodedUI in VS 2015?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I'm using VS 2015 Enterprise. I'm new to CodedUI testing. I've added a CodedUI test project to my solution. I've created a simple test, clicked on a button, selected a radio button, etc.

I've been following a Pluralsight course titled "Test Automation with CodedUI". I want to find a control on the WPF form, but once I select the control finder in the test builder and move the mouse off to the running application, it is no longer a bulls eye. I don't understand why its different than what's shown in the Pluralsight course. I think the instructor used VS 2012. Could that be the reason?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are subtle changes between versions. After clicking the assertion builder button in the Coded UI recorder then, as you move the mouse pointer around the screen (do not move it too fast or you will confuse yourself), you should see a blue rectangle drawn around parts of the screen. As you move the mouse pointer carefully you should be able to select larger or smaller sections, corresponding to higher or lower items within the hierarchy of controls on the screen. Click on a control of interest. You should then see a window showing the properties of the selected control. There are four arrows (up, down, left and right) in the new window. Click on these to navigate around the control hierarchy. Note that and 'up' followed by a 'down' will seldom return to the same control. The 'up' moves the parent control and the 'down' moves to the first child.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion here would be to use the keyboard shortcut to enable the control finder. When you hover over it with your mouse you should see it - if I recall correctly it's "Alt + H". Basically you'll move your mouse to the control you want to identify, then do the keyboard shortcut, then click. It should identify the control correctly at that point.